# Find the distribution of maximum of $B_t-t$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $B_t$ be a standard Brownian motion. It is easy to show that $\sup B_t-t<\infty$ a.s. . The question is, can we determinate the distribution of $\sup_{t\in [0,\infty)}B_t-t$?

Answer (score 3):

The process $M$ defined by $M_t = \exp(2B_t-2t)$ is a non-negative continuous martingale starting at $1$ and converging to $0$. Given $a \ge 0$, the values of $M$ until $\tau_a :=  \inf\{t \ge a : B_t-t \ge a\}$ belong to $[0,\exp(2a)]$. Hence optional topping theorem applies at time $T_a$ so
$$1 = \mathbb{E}[M_0] = 
 \mathbb{E}[M_{T_a}] = \exp(2a)\mathbb{P}[T_a < +\infty].$$
As a result,
$$P[\sup_{t\in [0,\infty)}B_t-t \ge a] = P[T_a < +\infty] = \exp(-2a).$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more general result:

Note that
$$P(\max_{s\in[0,t]}(W_s-b s)<a)=P(\tau>t), \tag{A}\label{A}$$
where $W_\cdot$ is the standard Wiener process, $a\in[0,\infty)$, $b\in\mathbb R$,
$$\tau:=\tau_{a,b}:=\inf\{s>0\colon X_s=0\},$$
$$X_t:=a+bt+W_t.$$

> **Proposition 1:**
> For any real $t>0$ and any real $x$,
> \begin{equation*}
>     P(X_t\in dx,\tau>t)=f_t(x-a-bt)(1-e^{-2ax/t})\,1(x>0)\,dx, 
> \end{equation*}
> where $f_t$ is the pdf of $W_t$.

Integrating here in $x$ and using \eqref{A}, we get
$$P(\max_{s\in[0,t]}(W_s-b s)<a)=P(\tau>t) \\
=\frac{1}{2} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{a+b t}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{t}}\right)-e^{-2 a b}
   \text{erfc}\left(\frac{a-b t}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{t}}\right)+1\right). \tag{B}\label{B}$$
Letting here $t\to\infty$, we get
$$P(\max_{s\in[0,\infty)}(W_s-b s)<a)=1-e^{-2 a b_+}, \tag{C}\label{C}$$
where $b_+:=\max(0,b)$.

It remains to provide the

*Proof of Proposition 1:*
The process $X_\cdot$ is continuous. So, $X_t>0$ on the event $\{\tau>t\}$. So, without loss of generality $x>0$.

For $s\in[0,t]$, let $B_s:=W_s-\frac st\,W_t$. Then $(B_s)_{s\in[0,t]}$ is (a Brownian bridge and it is) independent of $W_t$.
So,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    &P(X_t\in dx,\tau>t) \\ 
    &=P(X_t\in dx,\ X_s>0\ \forall s\in[0,t]) \\ 
    &=P(X_t\in dx,\ W_s>-a-bs\ \forall s\in[0,t]) \\ 
    &=P(W_t\in dx-a-bt,\ B_s>-a-bs-\tfrac st\,(x-a-bt)\ \forall s\in[0,t]) \\ 
    &=P(W_t\in dx-a-bt,\ B_s>-a-\tfrac st\,(x-a)\ \forall s\in[0,t]) \\ 
    &=P(W_t\in dx-a-bt)\,P(B_s>-a-\tfrac st\,(x-a)\ \forall s\in[0,t]) \\ 
    &=\frac{P(W_t\in dx-a-bt)}{P(W_t\in dx-a)}\,P(W_t\in dx-a)P(B_s>-a-\tfrac st\,(x-a)\ \forall s\in[0,t]) \\ 
    &=\frac{P(W_t\in dx-a-bt)}{P(W_t\in dx-a)}\,P(W_t\in dx-a,\ B_s>-a-\tfrac st\,(x-a)\ \forall s\in[0,t]) \\ 
    &=\frac{P(W_t\in dx-a-bt)}{P(W_t\in dx-a)}\,P(W_t\in dx-a,\ W_s>-a\ \forall s\in[0,t]) \\ 
    &=\frac{P(W_t\in dx-a-bt)}{P(W_t\in dx-a)}\,P(W_t\in a-dx,\ W_s<a\ \forall s\in[0,t]).  
\end{aligned}
\tag{0}\label{eq:}
\end{equation}
The first three equalities in \eqref{eq:} follow by the definitions of $\tau$, $X_\cdot$, and $B_\cdot$; the 5th and 7th equalities there follow by the independence of $(B_s)_{s\in[0,t]}$ from $W_t$; the penultimate equality in \eqref{eq:} follows again by the definition of $B_\cdot$; and the last equality in \eqref{eq:} follows by symmetry.
Next,
\begin{equation}
    \frac{P(W_t\in dx-a-bt)}{P(W_t\in dx-a)}=\frac{f_t(x-a-bt)}{f_t(x-a)}. \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation}
Further, letting $M_t:=\max_{s\in[0,t]}W_s$ and using the reflection principle for the Brownian motion, we get
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&   P(W_t\in a-dx,\ W_s<a\ \forall s\in[0,t]) \\ 
&=P(W_t\in a-dx,\ M_t<a) \\   
&=P(W_t\in a-dx)-P(W_t\in a-dx,\ M_t\ge a) \\   
&=P(W_t\in a-dx)-P(W_t\in a+dx) \\  
&=f_t(a-x)\,dx-f_t(a+x)\,dx 
=f_t(x-a)(1-e^{-2ax/t})\,dx.    
\end{aligned}
\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation}
Collecting \eqref{eq:}, \eqref{1}, and \eqref{2}, we complete the proof.
$\quad\Box$